# .htaccess rewrite rule: i cant access folders, only php files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

**Well this is meant to remove the php extension and to find /login and match it with /login.php for example**

**It is working fine, but when i need to enter a folder /something it tries to match it with /something.php so i get a 404 error.**

How can I make this rule to let me accesss folders too?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^login(/?|/.*)$ /login.php [QSA]
```

Comment: hi, well the login was just an example. i wanted to remove all the php extensions

Comment: Ah, I see. Then keep your existing rewrite rule and then make special exceptions for the directories you actually have. For example, use: `RewriteRule ^something/(.*)$ - [NC,QSA]`

Comment: ok, i would just need to replace the something with the directories i need?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, you should put these exceptions above your rule and include the an L at the end too `[NC,L,QSA]` to signify it's the last thing it should match.

Comment: Hi thanks for your time: http://blog.gotune.to/wp-admin/ that ends in an 404 error, but when i go to http://blog.gotune.to/wp-admin/index it enters the page.

the rewrite rule is: 

RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*)$ - [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [QSA]

Comment: I think I see the problem, try changing your rules to look like this: `RewriteRule ^wp-admin(/?|/.*)$ - [NC,L,QSA] RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [QSA]`